# What is the maximum for Pearson's chi square statistic?

Tags: chi-squared-test

I actually know that the answer is $N(k-1)$  (where $k$ is the minimum between number of rows and number of columns).

However, I can not seem to find a simple proof for why the statistic is bounded by this.  Any suggestions (or references?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For some intuition about this, consider the square case ($k$ rows and columns), with $N=nk$.  Then the maximal Chi Square occurs when all the marginal total are equal (in this case $n$), and the values in the table are $n$ along the diagonal and $0$ for the off diagonal, so that you have perfect association between the row and column variables.  Then the Chi Square statistic is $$ \sum (O-E)^2/E = k\cdot(n-n/k)^2/(n/k)+k\cdot(k-1)\cdot(0-n/k)^2/(n/k)$$ where the first part represents the sum of the k diagonal elements and the second part is the sum of the off diagonal elements.  You can show that this sum is $nk(k-1)=N(k-1)$.  Similar reasoning extends to the case where the number of rows and columns are not the same.

Comment: One might add that for different number of rows and columns, $k$ then must be the minimum of these two.

Comment: I tried solving this myself, gave up, and wrote a follow up question here:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13721/when-is-the-maximum-achieved-for-the-chi-square-statistic-for-a-nonsymetric-table